# PHP detect regex of n repetition characters

Tags: php, regex

How can i detect a sequence of n repetition of a pair of char.

Example:

`/(A{n})(B{n})/i`
for `AAABBB` or `AAAAABBBBB`
Not for `AABBBB` or `AAABB`

`/(A{n})(BB{n})/i`
for `AABBBB` or `AAABBBBBB`
Not for `AABBB` or `AAABB`

Comment: The easiest way to do this is recursive regex

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but for the first example, you may use `\b(A(?1)?B)\b` and for the second, `\b(A(?1)?B{2})\b`

Comment: specify the number of repetitions directly `\bA{3}B{3}\b` for each separate case

Comment: do you mean a regex that can find you even and/or odd pars?

Comment: not working... In need a regex that recognize same n repetition of characters

Comment: for example 

AAABBBAAAABBBBAABB

RECOGNIZE

AAABBB
AAAABBBB
AABB

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i had sequence of n char, i can't specify the number of repetition

Comment: /(A+)(B+)/i mismatch with  /(A+)(BB+)/i in the sequence AABBAAABBB

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Agt85M/1 and https://regex101.com/r/Agt85M/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in the first case i don't want to match AB but minimum AABB and higher repetition

Comment: Go the easier way, use a negative lookahead - [`\b(?!AB\b)(A(?1)?B)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Agt85M/3)

Comment: I must say this question is strikingly similar to your previous question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 

ABC

=> AABBCC......AAAABBBBCCCC ... etc

and this case?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew help me please!

Comment: Hi, I am looking after the kids now, sorry, I am not sure what you mean. Perhaps, a regex alone is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! If i wanna detect ABC sequence instead only AB?

Example QQQNNAAAAAABBBCCCCCCCCTTT detect AAABBBCCC

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You keep changing what you are asking for. First it was [A]=[N] and [A2]=[B]. Now you add another letter and what a match across all three. And if that is not enough you want a "free floating match" across them where based on the lowest count. That and the fact that you have completely ignores me an my answer hereby grants you a downvote and a flag for closing this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but it seems to work.

https://3v4l.org/LqVVA

```
$input = "AABBAAABBBBBB";
preg_match_all("/A+|B+/", $input, $parts);
//var_dump($parts);

for ($i=0; $i<=count($parts[0])-1; $i++){
    if(strlen($parts[0][$i]) ==  strlen($parts[0][$i+1]) && strlen($parts[0][$i]) > 1 && strlen($parts[0][$i]) > 1){
        echo "match " . $parts[0][$i] ." " . $parts[0][$i+1]. "\n";
    }else if(strlen($parts[0][$i])*2 ==  strlen($parts[0][$i+1]) && strlen($parts[0][$i]) > 1 && strlen($parts[0][$i]) > 1){
        echo "match " . $parts[0][$i] ." " . $parts[0][$i+1]. "\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

EDITED to add your requrement of minimum two char to match from comments above.

Edited again, Forgot about the AABBBB match

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in correct but detect simple sequence AB, i want to detect AABB minimum

Comment: It only echo AABB minimum. It will detect them all in preg_match but the for loop will only echo minimum of two char.